# Ubuntu 12.04 - Run a few command lines at every startup

Tags: command-line, 12.04, autorun

I was wondering if there is any way that I can run certain command lines through the terminal automatically at every start up of the computer.

I have a wacom tablet and it is quite annoying to turn the desire settings every time the system is restarted. For example, I want the following lines to run automatically:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch" touch off
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad" button 1 "key up"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad" button 3 "key down"
```

Is it possible to run it automatically at every startup?

Comment: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is to just plain add the lines to `/etc/rc.local`, which will run them at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

If you want to make it reusable over multiple machines, you may want to put in the effort to instead [make it into an upstart script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).